# Awk program to compare number of fields by space of each line

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to check if each line has a same length(or number of fields) in a file.
I am doing the following but it seems not to work.

`NR==1 {length=NF}`

`NR>1 && NF!=length {print}`

Can this be done by a one-liner awk? or a program is fine.

A sample of input would be:

```
12 34 54 56
12 89 34 33
12
29 56 42 42
```

My expected output would be "yes" or "no" if they have the same number of fields or not.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you mean to say you want to check all lines of Input_file and see if they ALL have same fields or not? Could you please  confirm once? Also you could mention sample of input and sample of expected output too in your post and let us know then?

Comment: I want to check all lines and see if they have the same number of fields.

Comment: Your code prints all lines with the same number of fields as the first line's. Look into `!=` and `exit`.

Comment: `seems not to work`? if it's not producing a syntax error since `length` is a function name then your awk is broken, get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to check fields of all lines, if they are equal or not if this is case then try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  value=NF
  count++
  next
}
{
  count=NF==value?++count:count
}
END{
  if(count==FNR){
     print "All lines are of same fields"
}
  else{
     print "All lines are NOT of same fields."
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Additional stuff(only if require):*** In case you want to print contents of file whose all lines are having same fields along with `yes` or `all are same fields in file` message in output then try following.

```
awk '
{
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0
}
FNR==1{
  value=NF
  count++
  next
}
{
  count=NF==value?++count:count
}
END{
  if(count==FNR){
    print "All lines are of same fields" ORS val
  }
  else{
    print "All lines are NOT of same fields."
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: Does this check the number of fields or the fields themselves?

Comment: @OldDUck, number of fields it will check, will add explanation in few mins too.

Comment: `count=NF==value?++count:count` is pretty darn cryptic. Some white space and parentheses would go a long way but then you'd still have `count = ++count` in the "true" leg which isn't trivial to 100% predict the result of! How about `count += (NF==value ? 1 : 0)` instead (if that's what your code does)?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a="yes"} last!="" && NF!=last{a="no"; exit} {last=NF}  END{print a}' file
```

#### How it works

- `BEGIN{a="yes"}`

  This initializes the variable `a` to `yes`.  (We assume all lines have the same number fields until proven otherwise.)
- `last!="" && NF!=last{a="no"; exit}`

  If `last` has been assigned a value *and* the number of fields on the current line is not the same as last, then set `a` to `no` and exit.
- `{last=NF}`

  Update `last` to the number of fields on the current line.
- `END{print a}`

  Before exiting, print `a`.

#### Examples

```
$ cat file1
2 34 54 56
12 89 34 33
12
29 56 42 42
$ awk 'BEGIN{a="yes"} last!="" && NF!=last{a="no"; exit} {last=NF}  END{print a}' file1
no
$ cat file2
2 34 54 56
12 89 34 33
29 56 42 42
$ awk 'BEGIN{a="yes"} last!="" && NF!=last{a="no"; exit} {last=NF}  END{print a}' file2
yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this command which checks the number of fields in each line and compares it to the number of fields of the first line:

```
awk 'NR==1{a=NF; b=0} (NR>1 && NF!=a){print "No"; b=1; exit 1}END{if (b==0) print "Yes"}' test.txt
```

Checking is aborted in the first line whose number of fields is distinct from the first line of input.

For input

```
12 43 43
12 32
```

you will get "No"

Answer (score 1):

this should do

```
$ awk 'NR==1{p=NF} p!=NF{s=1; exit} END{print s?"No":"Yes"}' file
```

however, setting the exit status would be better if this will be part of a workflow.

Since equivalence has transitive property, there is no need to keep NF other than the first line; setting `0` as your success value doesn't require initialization to default value.

Comment: nice. nit-pick - at a glance I thought `s` would've meant `same` so I was thrown by the logic at first. I'd have expected the variable name to maybe be `d` when it means `different`.

Comment: Yes, single char variables are cryptic, meaning should be derived from context.  Here I meant it for *status*, as in *status code* when exiting the script if you change `print  ...` to `exit s`.

Comment: Hmm, the one thing I DIDN'T think it meant was `status` since you said `however, setting the exit status would be better` so that sounds like you aren't setting the status and then you aren't exiting with a specific status. You're right though, single char variables could mean anything, and I do now understand what you were thinking in naming it `s`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An efficient ***e****ven* ***f****ields* shell function, using `sed` to construct a *regex*, (based on the first line of input), to feed to *GNU* `grep`, which looks for field length mismatches:

```
# Usage: ef filename
ef() { sed '1s/[^ ]*/[^ ]*/g;q' "$1" | grep -v -m 1 -q -f - "$1" \
       && echo no || echo yes ; }
```

For files with uneven fields `grep -m 1` quits after the first non-uniform line -- so if the file is a million lines long, but the mismatch occurs on line #2, `grep` only needs to read two lines, not a million.  On the other hand, if there's no mismatch `grep` would have to read a million lines.